# detect audio data peaks using waveform image (not using web audio)

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I was reading [G. Skinner's take](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2011/03/music-visualizer-in-html5-js-with-source-code.html) on using an image to detect volume peaks in order to create a custom visualizer display for audio and was wondering If anyone ever tried it using waveform images( like from soundcloud) to detect the peaks( volume/ amplitude/ frequency or whatever the term is) from an audio file. I want to use this as an alternative to using the Web Audio API which is a bit more tedious if you ask me and not supported in older devices( android 4.0).

Is there a way to process the colour data from a waveform image that can use to simulate such tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You can access raw pixel data from an image by using a `canvas` element and the Canvas API. You can render an image into a a canvas like so:

```
// getting the waveform image by loading it over HTTP
var waveformImage = new Image();

waveformImage.onload = onImageLoad;
waveformImage.src = 'path/to/waveform/image/file.jpg';

function onImageLoad() {

    // create a canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    // get the rendering context for the canvas
    var renderingContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // render the image to the canvas with drawImage()
    renderingContext.drawImage(waveformImage, 0, 0);

    // retrieve the raw pixel data using the width and height
    // properties of the image (which is this, since we are attaching
    // this method directly to waveformImage.onload
    var imageData = renderingContext.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    // process imageData from here, imageData is an ImageData instance
    // see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData
}
```

This example is largely based on the MDN example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData). Once you have your raw image data you can use whatever algorithms your research provides to extract amplitude or whatever audio information you need from the waveform.